# Iterators substracting

Tags: java, iterator, guava

I have 2 Iterator and need to return as result one Iterator that contain Objects that are in first minus Objects contained in second.
Is there any nice way of doing it with Apache.commons or Guava?

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: @Pravin There is nothing to share. Asking for direct method :)

Comment: Are there any guarantees you can make about the order of the elements?

Comment: Shouldn't you want to return a List or Set instead of an iterator?

Comment: Iterators dont contain objects, iterators are a way of accessing a collection one after another.

Comment: at the end I can trasfer all to Lists and manipulate was thinking if there is some more elegant way like when you do concat of 2 Iterators or something similar.

Comment: Do you have the two collections at hand where the iterators are gained from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need the *whole* second iterator when deciding if *any* member of the first belongs to the result. For deciding this efficiently, a `Set` is better than a `List`. The Guava solution is pretty simple:

```
return Iterators.filter(first,
    Predicates.not(Predicates.in(ImmutableSet.copyOf(second))));
```

Comment: definitely elegant  :)

Comment: Impressive! Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Using Iterators (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html), you can concat the two iterators and return them as an array, wrap with a collection, and finally remove all the elements for a collection with the second elements.

Here's my implementation:

```
public <E> List<E> remove(Iterator<E> a, Iterator<E> b) {       
    List<E> remove = Lists.newArrayList(b);
    Iterators.removeIf(a, new Predicate<>() {
        @Override public boolean apply(E e) {
            return remove.contains(e);
        }
    });

    return Lists.newArrayList(a);
}
```

This is my final solution (I have edits).

Comment: Another simple way, yes. But the question was about Apache.commons or guava libraries

Comment: @Andremoniy This *is* using Guava's Iterators class (lol) :P as is yours, I happened to stumble upon a similar method on Iterators as well.

Comment: i came to similar solution. just done at the end list.iterator() to return Iterator again. Will try to do it with predicate seems more compact :)

Comment: Your list construction is pretty overcomplicated. It should read: `List<E> list = Lists.newArrayList(a);`. And your concat makes no sense at all, just use `a`.

Comment: @maaartinus Hey, calm down man, thanks for the suggestions though. I'm familiar with Guava, but not completely fluent with it.

Comment: @Akosha I have some edits, in case you need to be notified to see them.

Comment: I'm calm, but I'm afraid it won't work. Look at `removeIf` or try it out.

Comment: @maaartinus I agree, it is difficult to code on a mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Good question indeed. There is similar to your task class in `apache.commons` - `IteratorUtils`. There is a method `public static ListIterator filteredListIterator(ListIterator listIterator, Predicate predicate)`, which you can use in such style:

```
final Iterator iterator1 = ...
final Iterator iterator2 = ...

Iterator iterator3 = IteratorUtils.filteredIterator(iterator1, new Predicate() {

    private List list = IteratorUtils.toList(iterator2);

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
           return !list.contains(object);
    }
});
```